# Django-registration, mail activation fails after force email unique (bad signature)

Tags: django, django-registration

I have a problem with django-registration. Everything works fine until I forced unique email.

I have very basic skeleton of app. This works fine:

```
auth_patterns = [
    url(r'^', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
]

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', login_required(HomeView.as_view()), name='index'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include(auth_patterns)),
)
```

But when I added

```
url(r'^register/$',
        RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmail),
        name='registration_register'
    ),
```

in auth_patterns I get activation link on mail

```
http://localhost:8000/en/accounts/activate/98a3585128c1b6899e4493768d4e62a52764fc5f/
```

but after click I got

```
Account activation failed
```

from my template (activate.html)

I have no errors in browser console/ or ./manage.py runserver outputs, nothing. When I tried to debug registration plugin I've noticed that registration plugin return user as None in this code (registration.backends.hmac.views.ActivationView):

```
def validate_key(self, activation_key):
    """
    Verify that the activation key is valid and within the
    permitted activation time window, returning the username if
    valid or ``None`` if not.

    """
    try:
        username = signing.loads(
            activation_key,
            salt=REGISTRATION_SALT,
            max_age=settings.ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS * 86400
        )
        return username
    # SignatureExpired is a subclass of BadSignature, so this will
    # catch either one.
    except signing.BadSignature:
        return None
```

It throw BadSignature, but why? Anyone had this problem? How to resolve it?

Comment: Have you changed the `SECRET_KEY` setting?

Comment: Did you get this working in the end? I am having similar problem and at the verge to drop RegistrationFormUniqueEmail.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate it has been moved on now. I am using django-registration==2.3

Have following to urls.py, it should work:

from registration.backends.hmac.views import RegistrationView
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

class RegistrationViewUniqueEmail(RegistrationView):
    form_class = RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

...
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationViewUniqueEmail.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
```

Comment: Works perfectly.